# Convert C data type to Python

Tags: python, c, types

I want to bind multiple size of data such as one byte value, two byte value, one byte value and then string.
This is a packet to be sent by a simple chatting client.

The network packet I want to make is in the diagram. Total 4 bytes header followed by body.
[image]

How can I make this packet by Python??

Is there any solution for storing data with explicit definition of size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Python's `struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). Here's an example of how to do what you're asking with `struct`:

```
from struct import *
header = pack('!chcs', clientID, bodySize, networkMessageId, body)
```

Now `header` will have that packet in it, and you can send it over the network (or whatever you need to do with it).

Since your image says "network" I assume this needs to be in network byte order, that's what the `!` at the beginning means.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
But how can i define the size of members in pack??
especially, i want to store 2-byte value in bodysize

Comment: See the documentation on `struct` that I linked ([or jump directly to the table here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)). The characters in the string given to `pack` specify the size. `c` means a single byte, `h` means a short integer (and short integers are two bytes by python's definition), and `s` is for a string.

Comment: So the string `!chcs` literally reads as: "put the following parameters in network byte order into an array with sizes: 1 byte, 2 bytes, 1 byte, and a string". Note that I made up the names `clientID`, `networkMessageId`, etc. you should replace these with the data you want to send.

Comment: You're welcome, if you feel your question is answered you can click the green checkmark to accept this answer. This helps other users know which questions still need help.